# How can parse special xml tag data under iOS swift?

Tags: ios, xml, swift2

I can parse standard xml format in swift. But I have some special xml tag, I don't know how can I parse it. xml output like this:

```
<Organisation status="happened">
 <Event title="Picnic">
 <Organisator name="Facebook" ID="1" URL=""/>
 <Info StartTime="12:30:00"/>
 </Event>
</Organisation>
```

I want to retrieve title, name, start time etc... Thank you for help

My codes like this:

```
    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

    element = elementName

    if(elementName as NSString) .isEqualToString("Song")
    {
        elements = NSMutableDictionary()
        elements = [:]
        title1 = NSMutableString()
        title1 = " "
        name = NSMutableString()
        name = " "
        time = NSMutableString()
        time = " "

    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {

    if element .isEqualToString("title")
    {
        title1.appendString(string)
    }
    else if element.isEqualToString("name")
    {
        name.appendString(string)
    }
    else if element.isEqualToString("time")
    {
        time.appendString(string)
    }
}


func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if (elementName as NSString) .isEqualToString("Organisation")
    {
        if !title1 .isEqual(nil)

        {
            elements.setObject(title1, forKey: "title")
        }

        if !name .isEqual(nil)
        {
            elements.setObject(name, forKey: "name")
        }
        if !time.isEqual(nil)
        {
            elements.setObject(time, forKey: "time")
        }

        myArray.addObject(elements)
    }
}
```

Comment: Show what you have tried by updating your question with relevant code. Are you using NSXMLParser? Have you tried accessing the element attributes?

Comment: Yes I am using NSXMLParser. I want to access element attributes

Comment: Again, update your question with your relevant code. Explain what issue you have getting the element attributes.

Comment: @rmaddy I updated question, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to make use of the `attributes` parameter in the `didStartElement` method?